# Yaws "process died" when yaws_api specific code is used

Tags: erlang, yaws

I have a small yaws appmod test:

```
-module(webservice).
-include("../include/yaws_api.hrl").
-compile(export_all).

http(parse_query,Arg) ->
    yaws_api:parse_query(Arg);

out(Arg) -> 
    {html, [http(parse_query,Arg)]}.
```

When the yaws_api:parse_query function is ran I get the following ERROR REPORT from the yaws interactive mode:

```
Yaws process died: {function_clause,
                   [{yaws_server,binary_size,
                        [0,{"i",undefined}],
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,3015}]},
                    {yaws_server,binary_size,2,
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,3018}]},
                    {yaws_server,binary_size,2,
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,3018}]},
                    {yaws_server,deflate_accumulated,4,
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,3712}]},
                    {yaws_server,deliver_accumulated,4,
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,3666}]},
                    {yaws_server,finish_up_dyn_file,2,
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,2745}]},
                    {yaws_server,aloop,4,
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,1175}]},
                    {yaws_server,acceptor0,2,
                        [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,1016}]}]}
```

The appmod is setup in config with:

```
<server localhost>
    port = 8080
    listen = 127.0.0.1
    #docroot = /usr/share/yaws
    docroot = /usr/lib/yaws/www
    appmods = </,webservice>
    # dir_listings = true
</server>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though you don't show it, it looks like the URL you're trying to access has a query string with at least one variable named `i`, something like this:

```
http://example.com/foo?i=10
```

For that URL, `yaws_api:parse_query/1` will return `[{"i","10"}]`, which you're then trying to return to Yaws as HTML using the `{html, iolist()}` construct. Unfortunately, `[{"i","10"}]` is not an iolist, string, or binary, so Yaws fails.

You can fix this by converting `[{"i","10"}]` to a string using the `yaws_api:f/2` call, like this:

```
out(Arg) ->
    {html, yaws_api:f("~p", [http(parse_query,Arg)])}.
```

or using the standard `io_lib:format/2` call:

```
out(Arg) ->
    {html, io_lib:format("~p", [http(parse_query,Arg)])}.
```

The `yaws_api:f/2` function is just a wrapper around `io_lib:format/2`.